# Isn't the "tempPtr" is redundant here? ( Linked Lists )

Tags: c, linked-list

I am practicing linked lists, and this is a code that is supplied to us by our lecturer, from a book by Pearson.

```
struct listNode {
    char data;
    struct listNode *nextPtr;
};

typedef struct listNode ListNode;
typedef ListNode *ListNodePtr;
```

...

```
char delete( ListNodePtr *sPtr, char value )
{
    ListNodePtr previousPtr;
    ListNodePtr currentPtr;
    ListNodePtr tempPtr;

    /* delete first node */
    if ( value == ( *sPtr )->data ) {
        tempPtr = *sPtr;
        *sPtr = ( *sPtr )->nextPtr;
        free ( tempPtr );
        return value;
    }
    else{
        previousPtr = *sPtr;
        currentPtr = ( *sPtr )->nextPtr;

        /* loop to find correct location in the list */
        while ( currentPtr != NULL && currentPtr->data != value ) {
            previousPtr = currentPtr;
            currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
        }

        /* delete node at currentPtr */
        if ( currentPtr != NULL ) {
            tempPtr = currentPtr;
            previousPtr->nextPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
            free ( tempPtr );
            return value;
        }       
    }

    return '\0';
}
```

I don't get why I'd need to use a "tempPtr". Could not I just do:

```
/* delete first node */
if ( value == ( *sPtr )->data ) {
    *sPtr = ( *sPtr )->nextPtr;
    free ( *sPtr );
    return value;
}
```

and

```
if ( currentPtr != NULL ) {
    previousPtr->nextPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
    free ( currentPtr );
    return value;
}
```

( What being passed to the `delete` function is a `LinkedListPtr` object defined in `main` and is passed by reference. It's responsible to hold address of first element in the list. )

Comment: `*sPtr = ( *sPtr )->nextPtr; free (*sPtr);` No your version is very wrong. The point of passing in `sPtr` is so that `*sptr` can be updated and returned to the caller if needed. That means `*sptr` must be a valid pointer when the function exits. Which it can't be if it has been freed.

Comment: Oh I was very suspicious about that part anyway, I see the problem. I was more focused on the second part. Is the second part also invalid?

Comment: Typedef pointers are bad style. I don't see how `typedef ListNode *ListNodePtr;` could be justified. Really `ListNode*` are two characters less to type and is really more clear it's a pointer then `ListNodePtr`. `Could not I just do:` - once you `free(*sPtr)` you can't use it. so `*sPtr->something` is invalid.

Comment: @KamilCuk I agree, I don't see the reason behind that either, and I don't use it. This is how the author of the book decided to go.

Comment: @KamilCuk Totally agree. I really don't understand why it seems may educators and text book writers in particular love to do that.

Comment: Most of the code is redundant. Too many special cases where they are not needed, IMHO.

Comment: It's a matter of taste. If you see the Win32 API they use the `TypePtr` style (actually `TYPEP` IIRC). There's some advantage, tiny as it be, in the fact that you will never make this mistake: `char *a_ptr, oops_not_a_ptr`.

Comment: No, there is no advantage. It forces readers to remember more (type)names.

Comment: @wildplasser, if I'm thinking what you're thinking, the solution would be to use double pointers. While fine and (IMO) a better solution, it may be hard to grasp on a beginners course, which I assume is the case here.

Comment: @Oppen : these *are* double pointers , tucked away behind ugly names.

Comment: @wildplasser, no, it doesn't, because that's why you have naming conventions. Also, it isn't either or. It can have the drawback of requiring to remember more things. That doesn't change the fact that the mistake I mentioned becomes impossible. I do prefer my pointer being pointers, but that doesn't mean the opposite is necessarily "bad",

Comment: @wildplasser, you're right about the double pointers.

Comment: You dont **need** to introduce an extra name if you can just use an additional `*`.

Comment: I think the worst part of that style is that it may be a never ending story, tho. `CHARPPPPPPPPPP`.
(You shouldn't have *that* many indirections, tho)

Comment: @Oppen Actually to me, it just made it harder to grasp. When I first tried to use this code as reference, it never occurred to me that someone would typedef a pointer in that way, and I was struggling to understand how it was working, than I realized that those are in fact a double pointers.

Comment: @wildplasser you're missing my point here. It isn't about the saved character, it's about the mistake you can make by not adding it.

Comment: @melonduofromage I'm not saying typedef pointers are easier to grasp, I'm saying a certain type of mistake can't happen with those. I think you're mixing two different conversations.

Comment: I.e., even while the advantages of avoiding that may be many (and I agree, they are), it's still not strictly black and white.

Comment: @melonduofromage I agree that your second case is correct and better than the original (IMHO).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplified version:

---

```
struct listNode {
    struct listNode *next;
    char data;
   };

char delete(struct listNode  **pp, char value )
{
    struct listNode  *this;

        while ((this = *pp)) {
                if (this->data != value) { pp= &this->next; continue; }
                *pp = this->next; // this is why you need a temp pointer
                free(this);       // ::because you want to free() it
                return value;     // nonsense return
        }

    return '\0'; // nonsense return
}
```

---

And a small driver to **test** the function:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct listNode {
    struct listNode *next;
    char data;
   };

struct listNode *root = NULL;

void push(char val)
{
struct listNode *new;
new = malloc (sizeof *new);
new->data = val;
new->next = root;
root = new;
}

void print(struct listNode *p)
{
for (; p; p = p->next) {
        printf(" %c", p->data);
        }
printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
push('o');
push('l');
push('l');
push('e');
push('H');

print(root);

delete( &root, 'o');
print(root);

delete( &root, 'H'); // <<-- test if we can delete the **first** node of the chain
print(root);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah. I was trying to simplify it myself but apparently failed at my first attempt. And interestingly the return of the function is never used at all.I had already omitted it.

Comment: The whole point is: you don't need the extra `if()`, because it duplicates the loop condition.

Comment: I didn't get something, doesn't this code change the value of "**pp" which is a "struct listNode*" defined in main and passed by reference? Won't it be pointing to the node next to deleted node after function is done?

Comment: `*pp` is part of the parent (or it belongs to the caller), and points to this. After the assigment, the parent will point to this->next. (and this can be deleted, since the parent does not point to it anymore)

Comment: But `pp` points to a pointer, which points to first node. `this` being assigned to `*pp`, so at this point `this` points to first node. When we are looping through, we do `pp = &(this->next);` so `pp` points to a pointer pointing to the next node. Say we found value at 5th node. After following commands, `*pp` points to 5th node, and `pp` points to it. When we terminate the function, isn't original pointer who supposed to point at the first node, now pointing to 5th node? I don't understand how it remains unmodified.

Answer (score 2):

> Could not I just do:
>
> ```
> if ( value == ( *sPtr )->data ) {
>     *sPtr = ( *sPtr )->nextPtr;           # this line changes *sPtr value
>     free ( *sPtr );                       # frees `(*sPtr)->nextPtr`, not the old `*sPtr`
>     return value;
> }
> ```

No, that's not equivalent. In your code you are freeing `(*sPtr)->nextPtr`, not `*sPtr`. You want to free the value of `*sPtr` *and* change it to the value of the next pointer. So you have to have a temporary value - either for the pointer or for the new value. Alternatively to the original code, you could save `nextPtr` and free the current pointer and then assign it to next:

```
if ( value == ( *sPtr )->data ) {
    tempPtr = (*sPtr)->nextPtr;
    free(*sPtr);
    *sPtr = tempPtr;
    return value;
}
```

> and
>
> ```
> if ( currentPtr != NULL ) {
>     previousPtr->nextPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
>     free ( currentPtr );
>     return value;
> }
> ```

Sure, that code is equivalent.